# Stop Post Data From Different Domain PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm a beginner in PHP.

What I'm trying to do is stop Post Data coming from another webpage.

The problem I am having is let's say someone copies my form and pastes it in their website. I want to be able to stop that Post Data from running the script on my email form.

How can I do this? Let me know if I'm not being clear enough.

My PHP Contact form runs on one page with conditional statements. i.e. if data checks out, submit.

Comment: I've also tried checking the URL in PHP, but then I found out that was an amateur mistake.

Comment: Ok. I've looked over what you guys have given me, and I have thought of a different idea using what you guys gave me...What if I randomized a set of characters => converted to a variable, posted it as the hidden value so it changes every time, and check for that when my script runs?

Comment: amateur mistake again.....sorry.

Comment: thanks everyone! couldn't have done it without everyone's help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$_SERVER['HTTP_Referrer'] would be nice but it isn't reliable.  You could use a hidden form field that MD5's something and then you check it on the other side.

Comment: What if I did randomized the number and posted it as a hidden value, but it changes.

Comment: oh wait, they can just remove that hidden value and make it work....lol. dangit,just when I think i'm getting the grips of PHP.

Comment: I think I finally figured it out, I used session_start, made a sessions variable when the form was shown, and then checked to see if the variable was set to submit!

Comment: Are you using server side sessions?

Comment: No, I am not using server side sessions. 

And my logic up above didn't didn't work. sorry guys.

Comment: the only problem when I MD5 my string is that, the person can grab that hidden value and place it on their site. This will only work temporarily until a new string is generated in the hidden value. in other words until someone refreshes the page.

Comment: figured out how to use the http referer on this page: http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Check-Referrer-Prevent-Linking-Sites_t40295.html

Comment: You can't trust the HTTP_Referrer though, it's easily spoofed.

Comment: yeah, i'm also using the randomized hidden field and checking it before submit using sessions. any other ideas that are useful for checking unique user identity and preventing CSRF?

Comment: no kidding, about easily spoofing the http referer - I used the Firefox Add On: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/953 and quickly spoofed the referer, Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you meant you were only check the Referrer.

Answer (score 16):

**"accepted answer" has security holes**. Instead, you should use more secure methods. A simple example:

**Step 1:** Disable framing of the page (`.php`), where the form is generated, in the top add:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: Deny');
```

**Step 2: (important part ! ):** In order to avoid XSS and 3rd party exploits, you should create a expirable validation.
For example:

- `ASP.NET` builtin forms use dynamic input **csrf** (example value: `gtlkjh29f9ewduh024cfvefb` )
- `WordPress` builtin forms use dynamic input **nonce** (example value: `340297658942346` )

So, if you are on a custom platform, which doesn't have built-in temporary token validation methods, then implement your approach. A simple concept:

```
<?php  
$secret_key      = 'fjd3vkuw#KURefg';  //change this
$encrypted_value = Cryptor::encrypt( time(), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $secret_key);
?>
<form>
...
...
<input value="<?php echo $encrypted_value;?>" name="temp_random" type="hidden"  />
</form>
```

*(Cryptor code is [here](https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/two-way-encrypt-decrypt.php) )*

on submission, check:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){

   // If REFERRER is empty, or it's NOT YOUR HOST, then STOP it
   if( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']) || parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'])['host'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ){
       exit("Not allowed - Unknown host request! ");
   }

   // Now, check if valid
   if (   Cryptor::decrypt(  $_POST['temp_random'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $secret_key) < time() - 60* 15 ) {
       exit("Not allowed - invalid attempt! ");
   }

   ...........................................
   ... Now, you can execute your code here ...
   ...........................................

}
```

Comment: This allows a 500 Internal Server Error for "Uncaught Exception - Encryption failure" (I determined it to be at line 143 of Cryptor script) when the 'temp_random' string is missing or incomplete (as I tested using Developer Tools.) I resolved this by implementing a "try...catch" statement. I also chose to add a 403 server response for the exit message. Additionally, there is a misspelling of HTTP_REFERER

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to prevent [CSRF - Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).  [Jeff himself](https://blog.codinghorror.com/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks/) has a blog article about this.

True XSRF Prevention requires three parts:

- Hidden Input Fields, to prevent someone from just snatching the form and embedding it
- Timechecking within an epsilon of the form being generated, otherwise someone can generate a valid form once and use the token (depending on impementation/how it's stored)
- Cookies: this is to prevent a malicious server from pretending it's a client, and performing a man-in-the-middle attack

Answer (score 2):

In the form:

```
<?
$password = "mypass"; //change to something only you know
$hash = md5($password . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"iphash\" value=\"$hash\"/>";
?>
```

When you are checking:

```
$password = "mypass"; //same as above
if ($_POST['iphash'] == md5($password . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    //fine
}
else {
    //error
}
```

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR could be spoofed, so if there were a MITM attack this would prove worthless.  Also after I've made a single request I could easily make more by simply duplicating the hash, which would render this worthless, the 'unique' part of the hash needs to be more 'unique', which is why I chose to use time() witch provides the current epoch time.

Comment: The "attacker" isn't the client, its another server serving a form page to *his* clients.

Comment: Either way it can still happen just as easy.

Comment: I believe the same AJAX-Remote-Loading comment on Unkwntech's answer applies to this as well.  True XSRF protection requires cookies, hidden form input, and time-within-epsilon considerations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick-and-dirty approach, you can check the REFERER header.

If you really want to make sure that the form was fetched from your site though, you should generate a token each time the form is loaded and attach it to a session.  A simple way to do this would be something like:

```
$_SESSION['formToken'] = sha1(microtime());
```

Then your form can have a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value='<?=$_SESSION['formToken'];?>' />
```

and you can check that when deciding whether to process your form data.

Comment: Do you even need to check the token in $_POST?  Why not just check if the $_SESSION value is still set?

Answer (score 0):

Every user do signup and then obtain a login id.

Following is algorithm to prevent CSRF: -

```
1) $login_id = user login id (converted to a numeric id using mysql)
2) $a_secret_key = $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'];
3) $remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
4) Request Date and Time -> A unique reference key -> $refkey
5) $_SESSION['secretkey'] = $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'];
```

Combine aforesaid 1 to 4 to create a json file, when transferring data to another page.

Then

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"refkey\" value=\"$refkey\"/>";
```

At receiver's end:-

Receiver page should check if

```
1) any json file with $refkey exists at server?

2) If $refkey exists, then check $login_id, $a_secret_key and $remote_addr exists and are correct.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the highest score answer. It should be $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'].

Comment: You should add a comment to the accepted answer with this info instead of creating a new answer.

Comment: @AdrianGhiuta You are correct, however, commenting requires having a minimum of 50 reputation points. Answer and Edit are the only response options available for new members.